# Share tab disappered when viewing folder properties?

Tags: samba, shared-folders

When I tried to share a folder called test I found that the share tab was missing in folder properties.
I am wondering how to restore it as I think it disappeared after **samba4** was installed.

Here is a screen-shot of what I now see when I go into folder properties.

[image]

It should be like below screenshot :

[image]

Can anyone give any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-enable share tab :

Open Terminal and install **nautilus-share package** which is responsible for sharing folders :

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-share -y
```

That solve my situation and restore share tab .