# `Share` and `Details` tabs missing on Kubuntu

Tags: networking, kubuntu, nautilus, kde, samba

I managed to get Samba working and sharing files across the network. Everything worked fine, and then something happened and now my other computers cannot see the public folder I set up on the Kubuntu machine.

On my Kubuntu machine, when I right click on a folder and select Properties, the only tabs I'm seeing are General and Permissions. I remember there being a Share tab before (that's how I configured the public folder), but now it is missing.

I have no idea what I did to cause that, and no idea how to troubleshoot that.

<strike>I found a similar question here: [Share tab disappered when viewing folder properties?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426132/share-tab-disappered-when-viewing-folder-properties) however, I don't think that solution (to install `nautilus-share`) is applicable to KDE, but I could be mistaken. Should I try that?</strike>

EDIT 1:

OK, this is really strange. Both the `Details` and `Share` tabs appeared earlier today, without me doing anything (at least that I'm aware of). And I've checked it just now, and they are gone again! I have no idea what I've done... (I may have unplugged the network cable, while moving my laptop, that's the only thing that comes to mind).

EDIT 2:

I just attempted `Morbius1` suggestion and `net usershare info --long` correctly displays the info about the folder I'm sharing. I tried installing `kdenetwork-filesharing`, but it's already the newest version (4:18.04-3-0ubuntu2).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used KDE but that tab should come from the

```
kdenetwork-filesharing
```

package. Try installing or reinstalling it.

But if you already created some shares using it in the past they should still be valid, Run this command to see the share definitions:

```
net usershare info --long
```

*nautilus-share is the gnome equivalent to this package and I'm guessing it would pull in Nautilus which I suspect you would not want.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've ran `net usershare info --long` and it correctly finds the folder that I'm sharing. I tried installing `kdenetwork-filesharing` and I get: `kdenetwork-filesharing is already the newest version (4:18.04-3-0ubuntu2).`

The tabs appeared earlier today (before I tried this). Then they disappeared again. Then I tried this, without success. It's really weird....